# Em R, criar uma função para mudar alguns levels de uma variavel

Tags: r

Quero criar uma função que facilite minha vida na hora de tratar algumas variáveis

Quero uma função que receba como entrada uma base de dados, uma coluna ou variável u dessa base de dados, um vetor c especificando os levels a serem trocados e o novo nome que vai substituir tais levels.

Na verdade, tentei fazer isto diretamente com a função relevel, ma não achei muito fácil de usar.

Eu criei uma função que me retorna um vector tipo factor... mas na verdade, eu quero que a função transforme a matrix data de maneira que a variavel u já fique modificada... pois depois de usar a minha função e dou um levels(data$u) aparecem os levels antigos

```
  juntar<- function(data, u, c , novolevel)
 {

 ### Trasformamos nossa variável em tipo character
 data[,which(colnames(data)== u )]<- as.character(data[,which(colnames(data)== u )])

 levels<- c

 ### determinamos as coordenadas levels
 coordenadas_levels<- data[,which(colnames(data)== u )] %in% levels
 coordenadas_levels<- which(coordenadas_levels == TRUE)

 ### Fazemos a mudança
 data[,which(colnames(data)== u )][coordenadas_levels]<- novolevel

 ### Convertemos em factor
 data[,which(colnames(data)== u )]<- as.factor(data[,which(colnames(data)== u )])

 }
```

Obrigado

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fiz a seguinte função:

```
juntar <- function(dat, variavel, levls, novosLevls){
  # pega o nome da variável
  variavel <- deparse(substitute(variavel))
  # cria data frame auxiliar para dar merge
  aux <- data.frame(x = levls, .Novo = novosLevls)
  names(aux)[1] <- variavel

  # merge desse novo data frame
  dat <- merge(x = dat, y = aux, by = variavel, all.x = T)
  # substitui a variavel species pela nova
  dat[[variavel]] <- ifelse(is.na(dat$.Novo), as.character(dat[[variavel]]), as.character(dat$.Novo))
  # exclui a variavel nova
  exc <- names(dat) == ".Novo"
  dat <- dat[!exc]
  # retorna o data frame
  return(dat)
}
```

Acho que está funcionando. Testei com o data.set `iris` assim:

```
juntar(iris, Species, c("setosa", "virginica"), "novo") %>% head

  Species Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
1    novo          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1
2    novo          5.0         3.4          1.5         0.2
3    novo          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2
4    novo          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2
5    novo          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2
6    novo          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2
```

O último argumento `novosLvls` pode ser tanto um vetor do mesmo tamanho que o `levls` quanto um único valor.