# Em R, como definir uma função com argumentos indefinidos da mesma natureza

Tags: r

Caros, estou a definir uma função a partir de outra. Entretanto, quero definir minha nova função com vários argumentos da mesma natureza. Por exemplo

A minha função base é bem determinada

```
funcaobase(data, argumento1)
```

Mas a minha função nova quero que faça varias vezes isso de maneira determinada no argumento. Ou seja, na hora de definir, algo assim

```
NovaFuncao(data, argumento1, argumento2, argumento3, ...)
{

  data<- funcaobase(data, argumento1)
  data<- funcaobase(data, argumento2)     
  data<- funcaobase(data, argumento3)
  ...

  return(data)
 }
```

Mas gostaria de uma função de maneira que isto funcione

```
 NovaFuncao(data, argumento1, argumento2, argumento3, argumento4 , argumento5)
```

Não sei como dar procedimento a isto.

PS: Na verdade eu quero modificar esta questão que eu perguntei antes. de maneira que eu possoa modificar varios levels ao mesmo tempo - permanecendo na mesma variável- ou seja, algo como function(dat, variavelfixa, levls1, novosLevls2 , levls2, novosLevls2 , levls3, novosLevls3, ...) [Em R, criar uma função para mudar alguns levels de uma variavel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/48767/em-r-criar-uma-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-para-mudar-alguns-levels-de-uma-variavel)

Comment: Repare que na sua `NovaFuncao` você dá, em cada linha, um novo valor à `data`, de modo que você substitui o valor a cada nova linha e portanto, seu `return(data)` só irá  retornar o último valor associado a `data`. É isso mesmo que você pretende?

Comment: Eu dou um novo valor, mas não gostaria que esse feito se perdesse.

Comment: Se você quer que ele retorne todos os valores, basta criar uma lista que guarde estes valores e retornar a lista ao final. Se você puder nos dar um exemplo reprodutível, fica muito mais fácil ajudá-lo. A solução pode depender, por exemplo, da sua estrutura de dados (`data` é um data.frame? um vetor? uma lista?) e do que sua função faz.

Comment: Não existe uma maneira de usar os três pontos (...) para evitar repetir os argumentos?

Comment: Vamos lá. Na verdade eu quero modificar esta questão que eu perguntei antes. de maneira que eu possoa modificar varios levels ao mesmo tempo, o u seja, algo como function(dat, variavel, levls1, novosLevls2 , levls2, novosLevls2) http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/48767/em-r-criar-uma-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-para-mudar-alguns-levels-de-uma-variavel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primeiro respondendo o seu problema específico, com base no seu comentário.

A função de exemplo que você colocou lida com "non-standard" evaluation, o que torna mais difícil de programar com funcionais (como o `lapply`). Assim, vou criar uma outra função equivalente para ilustrar o seu caso.

A função abaixo pega um vetor de textos e substitui certas palavras (ou regular expressions) por outras:

```
mgsub <- function(replacement, pattern, x){
  aux <- data.frame(replacement, pattern)
  for(i in 1:nrow(aux)) x <- gsub(aux[i,1], aux[i,2], x)
  x
}
```

No exemplo dos dados `iris`, vamos trocar as espécies "setosa" e "virginica" por "novo":

```
iris$Species <- mgsub(c("setosa", "virginica"), "novo", iris$Species)
```

Ok, temos uma função que faz isso para um vetor de cada vez.  Agora somente precisamos de uma função que faça isso para vários vetores ao mesmo tempo. Vamos criar portanto uma nova função com `Vectorize()`.

```
NovaFuncao <- function(dados, variaveis, levels, novosLevels){
  dados[variaveis] <- Vectorize(mgsub, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)(levels, novosLevels, dados[variaveis])
  dados
}
```

Agora nossa função aceita um `data.frame`, um vetor com o nome das variáveis que serão substituídas, uma lista com os levels antigos e uma lista com os novos levels. Criando uma base de dados de teste:

```
df <- data.frame(fator1 = c("a", "b", "c"),
                 fator2 = c("f", "g", "h"),
                 fator3 = c("i", "j", "k"))
df
  fator1 fator2 fator3
1      a      f      i
2      b      g      j
3      c      h      k

NovaFuncao(df, 
           variaveis = c("fator1", "fator2"), 
           levels = list(c("a", "b"), 
                         c("f")),
           novosLevels = list(c("novo1", "novo2"),
                              c("novo3"))
           )
 fator1 fator2 fator3
1  novo1  novo3      i
2  novo2      g      j
3      c      h      k
```

Bom, mantendo abaixo a resposta genérica anterior:

---

Suponha que essa seja sua função base:

```
funcaobase <- function(data, argumento1){
  paste(data, argumento1)
}
```

Testando a função:

```
data <- "teste"
funcaobase(data, 1)
[1] "teste 1"
```

O que você quer é vetorizá-la no `argumento1` (a função `paste` já é vetorizada, então não precisaria fazer isso, mas apenas para ilustração vamos supor que ela não fosse).

```
NovaFuncao <- Vectorize(funcaobase, vectorize.args = "argumento1", SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

Agora você pode usar vários argumentos ao invés de um só:

```
argumentos <- 1:5
NovaFuncao(data, argumentos)
[[1]]
[1] "teste 1"

[[2]]
[1] "teste 2"

[[3]]
[1] "teste 3"

[[4]]
[1] "teste 4"

[[5]]
[1] "teste 5"
```

Mais detalhadamente, `Vectorize` usa o `lapply` ou `mapply`. Por exemplo, você pode fazer a mesma coisa com um `lapply` em argumentos mantendo `data` fixo:

```
lapply(argumentos, funcaobase, data=data)
[[1]]
[1] "teste 1"

[[2]]
[1] "teste 2"

[[3]]
[1] "teste 3"

[[4]]
[1] "teste 4"

[[5]]
[1] "teste 5"
```

Assim,  você pode transformar esse comando em uma nova função:

```
NovaFuncao <- function(data, argumentos){
  lapply(argumentos, funcaobase, data=data)
}

NovaFuncao(data, argumentos)
[[1]]
[1] "teste 1"

[[2]]
[1] "teste 2"

[[3]]
[1] "teste 3"

[[4]]
[1] "teste 4"

[[5]]
[1] "teste 5"
```

Essa é a lógica básica. Você pode fazer isso também com um `for` loop ou usando outras funções da família `apply` a depender do caso.

Comment: No meu caso, a minha função base depende de duas variáveis. Na verdade a minha função base eu chamei de juntar, e ela funciona assim: juntar(dat, variavel, levls, novosLevls). Onde dat é a minha base de dados, variavel é uma coluna, levels são alguns levels da coluna(variável) que eu quero modificar e novoLevls são os levels novos. Ou seja, eu quero algo assim: NovaFuncao(dat, variavel, levls1, novosLevls2, levls2, novosLevls2, ... ). Eu poderia colocar tudo de uma vez só. Só que eu quero fazer isto por grupos.

Comment: Ou seja, quero algo como: Mude este grupo de levels por este grupo. Este outro grupo de levels por este outro grupo.. e assim por diante

Comment: Ou já existe alguma função pronta para isto?

Comment: @Vasco sim dá para fazer com essas mesmas funções que passei, agora estou no celular, daqui a pouco coloco um exemplo

Comment: @Vasco coloquei um exemplo específico para seu caso.

Comment: Opa, sua resposta foi ótima e será muito útil. Gostaria de ser pertinente com a minha pergunta inicial. Eu quero trabalhar com uma variável só. Por exemplo, suponha que eu tenho uma variável com leveles: "a" , "b" , "c" , "d" , "e" , "f". Eu quero algo assim, Novafuncao(data, variavel, c("a" , "b" , "e"), "novo1" , c("c","d"), "novo2") de modo que meus novos levels sejam "novo1" , "novo2", "f". Na verdade eu não estou interessado nos levels e sim nas frequencias relativas. Por isso eu quero especificar varios grupos a serem mudados de maneira bem determinada.

Comment: Eu poderia fazer isto usando a funçao base duas vezes. Mas quero evitar isto pois acho mais prático

Comment: Para permanecer na mesma variável, eu tentei isto: NovaFuncao(df, variaveis = c("fator1", "fator1"),.....) Mas deu erro!

Comment: Poderia fazer isto fazendo um for, mas evito sempre evitar o for.

Comment: @Vasco, acho que entendi o que você quer fazer. Na verdade é bem mais simples então, você pode usar só a `mgsub` separando com |. Exemplo `fator <- c("a" , "b" , "c" , "d" , "e" , "f")` e `mgsub(c("a|b|e", "c|d"), c("novo1", "novo2"), fator)`

Comment: É simples, entretanto a sua opção de fazer a mesma coisa com várias variáveis é ótima. Gostei